# How can I copy specific wifi networks from one Android device to another?

Tags: data-transfer, certificates, wifi-password

I have a rooted Android 7.1.1 phone with a large number of wireless networks configured; some of these are relatively complicated (EAP-TTLS, custom CA certificate, whatnot; the point is it's more involved than just a shared secret).

I would like to copy *some* of these networks to another phone, also rooted (running reasonably recent LineageOS, likely Android 9 or 10), without overwriting other wifi configuration that exists on the destination phone.

I know I could use something like Titanium Backup (which I bought) to do a full backup of all wifi networks from the source phone and restore it on the destination phone, but that doesn't meet the following two needs:

1. don't transfer all, just some saved wifi networks;
2. don't overwrite existing networks on target device (just add new networks).

I'm also not certain it would correctly transfer the certificate along with the network it pertains to.

I looked at [How to copy wireless networks list from one android device to another?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28654/how-to-copy-wireless-networks-list-from-one-android-device-to-another/28663), but that also only addresses copying all networks, not cherry-picking.

I suppose I could merge the new networks into `wpa_supplicant.conf`, but is that safe to edit while Android is running? Won't changes be overwritten? (Update: it would, unless editing while in recovery mode; see [How to modify wpa_supplicant.conf](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/183685/how-to-modify-wpa-supplicant-conf)) (Also, I'd still need to find a way to transfer the CA certificates.)

Comment: Which Android version? On 10,I see  all the details in  `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`, with the password and network name in clear and `wpa_supplicant` is empty

Comment: I updated my question with further details.

Comment: [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rusdelphi.wifipassword) promises to sync them between devices – if you don't mind the trackers it comes with (those companies could get the data then as well: Google, Yandex, Facebook). Some alternatives can be found [in my list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_config) to e.g. copy one-by-one.

Comment: On Samsung S20FE (Android 12), passwords are saved in `/data/misc/apexdata/com.android.wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`.